# After renewing the SSL certificate the browser keeps displaying an SSL error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

After I have renewed the SSL certificate many visitors keep getting the message that there is not a valid certificate.

Question: how can I force the new certificate to be activated on all clients?

It is a WordPress site, I can not restart any services via DirectAdmin.

At the moment I have the following code in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests; env=HTTPS"
Header always set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
Header always set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
Header always set Feature-Policy "geolocation 'self'; vibrate 'none'"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This would seem to suggest an error with the SSL cert renewal? What is the URL/domain you are requesting? Any difference between the domain apex and www subdomains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not any issues with certificate maybe is just cache of your browser. Try clear data, or open in other device you should be done!

if you want redirect http connections to https add this following to `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I deleted the cache on my laptop, the certificate is fine. I can hardly send an email to 1500 people telling them to throw away the cache to see the website again.
Surely this should be able to be forced from the server?

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it out

Comment: This breaks the WordPress rewrite

Comment: please post all content whose is inside your .htaccess

Comment: Hi Aloiso, I just past the whole .htaccess I have

Comment: Try insert at top of your .htaccess ...


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do it either.

Comment: check this article, can be helpful https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747758-Force-your-site-to-load-securely-with-an-htaccess-file

Comment: Sorry Aloiso, I have one macbook with Safari and after I added the code in .htaccess the warning is still the same (no valid certificate)

Comment: You can't resolve an "invalid certificate" warning in the _browser_ by implementing a redirect on the _server_. The browser warning occurs during the initial stages of the SSL handshake - _before_ the request is processed by `.htaccess`.

Comment: Hi MrWhite how can I do that?